# Query datetime by today's date in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm saving `datetime` in the db for an object. I'd like to query against the db and select anything from todays `date`, not datetime.

What's the easiest way to do this? This doesn't work:

```
invoice_for_today = Invoice.objects.get(user=user, date=date.today())
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I remember there being plans to add a `__date` field lookup to make this easier, but as it stands the "standard" way of doing it is

```
today_min = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.time.min)
today_max = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.time.max)
Invoice.objects.get(user=user, date__range=(today_min, today_max))
```

Comment: Where can I import date from ?

Comment: @TaufiqMuhammadi `date` is `datetime.date`. `from datetime import date`, or just use `datetime.date.today()`

Comment: `__date` has been implemented in django1.9. [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#date).

Answer (score 39):

You can also do something like this:

```
today = date.today()
invoice_for_today = Invoice.objects.filter(date__year=today.year, date__month=today.month, date__day=today.day)
```

Comment: From the accepted answer datetime.time.max returned 'method_descriptor' object has no attribute 'max', but your answer works perfect, thanks!

Comment: timezone should be same for  database server and web server

Answer (score 27):

in django<1.9

```
from django.utils.timezone import datetime #important if using timezones
today = datetime.today()
foo_for_today = Foo.objects.filter(datefield__year=today.year, datefield__month=today.month, datefield__day=today.day)
```

in django>1.9, as they [added the date keyword](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#date)

```
foo_for_today = Foo.objects.filter(datefield__date=datetime.date.today())
```

Comment: With `datetime` from `Django,utils.timezone`, `datetime.date(datetime.today())` works.

Answer (score 14):

```
obj = TeachersPlanner.objects.filter(date__startswith=date.today())
```

Answer (score 9):

To get entries from the **Last 24 hours** you can use:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__gte = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1))
```

Answer (score 8):

There is a new __date field lookup in Django 1.9 you can use:

```
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__date=datetime.date(2005, 1, 1))
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__date__gt=datetime.date(2005, 1, 1))
```

[Queryset API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/)

Answer (score 6):

Try using the keys `date__gte` and `date__lte`. You can pass in two datetime objects marking the boundaries of what you want to match.