# python queryset date filter not change date to current date

Tags: python, django

My queryset filter did return the correct filtered data on the first date that I wrote the code but after that the date is stuck to that specific date and does not bring up the filtered information based on the current date.

What am I doing wrong?

```
today = datetime.date.today()
todaydate = today
url(r'^maanta/', ListView.as_view(
        queryset= Article.objects.filter(pub_date__startswith=todaydate),
        template_name="myarticle.html")),
```

Comment: see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217811/query-datetime-by-todays-date-in-django)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assign the date like you did on the module level, it is only evaluated once.

The trick is to use a lambda function:

```
todaydate = lambda: datetime.date.today()
```

And to adjust your lookup to:

```
Article.objects.filter(pub_date__startswith=todaydate())
```